# Tomcat8 failing to start in Ubuntu 16.04 in VirtualBox Vagrant on Windows Host

Tags: windows, ubuntu, ansible, vagrant, tomcat8

I'm not super familiar with vagrant and have an image for Ubuntu 16.04 with an ansible script that sets up and runs a tomcat8 server application. I went to set it up on a Windows host, and the tomcat service fails to start every time.

The result of running the ansible playbook is:

```
TASK [Restart tomcat] **********************************************************
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": true, "cmd": "service tomcat8 restart", "delta": "0:00:00.046020", "end": "2019-02-02 17:55:28.417905", "failed": true, "rc": 1, "start": "2019-02-02 17:55:28.371885", "stderr": "Job for tomcat8.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See \"systemctl status tomcat8.service\" and \"journalctl -xe\" for details.", "stdout": "", "stdout_lines": [], "warnings": ["Consider using service module rather than running service"]}
```

The result of trying to run `sudo service tomcat8 restart` is:

```
Job for tomcat8.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status tomcat8.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

Checking the service status via `sudo service tomcat8 status` gives:

```
● tomcat8.service - LSB: Start Tomcat.
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/tomcat8; bad; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2019-02-04 16:15:19 UTC; 46s ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 10703 ExecStop=/etc/init.d/tomcat8 stop (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 11859 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/tomcat8 start (code=exited, status=127)

Feb 04 16:15:19 vagrant systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Start Tomcat....
Feb 04 16:15:19 vagrant tomcat8[11859]: [58B blob data]
Feb 04 16:15:19 vagrant systemd[1]: tomcat8.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=127
Feb 04 16:15:19 vagrant systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: Start Tomcat..
Feb 04 16:15:19 vagrant systemd[1]: tomcat8.service: Unit entered failed state.
Feb 04 16:15:19 vagrant systemd[1]: tomcat8.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

I have tried reinstalling tomcat8 with apt-get, and that threw errors with prerm, and then postinst, so I removed all of the tomcat8.prerm, tomcat8.preinst, tomcat8.postinst, etc files and tried again with no luck. (Honestly don't remember the exact result of that - if needed I can try again and update this post)

I also tried manually installing tomcat8 before running the ansible playbook and the same thing happened.

I just feel like I've just been taking wild stabs and am not sure really where to start digging deep, so any and all ideas are greatly appreciated.

UPDATE: Turns out when this runs on a macOS host, this error does not occur..

UPDATE PART 2: I tracked down the problem child in the playbook:

```
- name: Configure tomcat memory
template:
  src: /home/vagrant/shared/resources/tomcat8
  dest: /etc/default/tomcat8
  mode: 0640
  force: True
```

If I remove that from the playbook, this error doesn't occur. I don't think it's related to the contents of the tomcat8 file, because I tried basically commenting out all the lines to go back to the default and still had the problem. I'm guessing it's something permissions related maybe? Nonetheless, here's what's in the file it's copying:

```
# Run Tomcat as this user ID. Not setting this or leaving it blank will use the
# default of tomcat8.
TOMCAT8_USER=tomcat8

# Run Tomcat as this group ID. Not setting this or leaving it blank will use
# the default of tomcat8.
TOMCAT8_GROUP=tomcat8

# The home directory of the Java development kit (JDK). You need at least
# JDK version 7. If JAVA_HOME is not set, some common directories for
# OpenJDK and the Oracle JDK are tried.
#JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk

# You may pass JVM startup parameters to Java here. If unset, the default
# options will be: -Djava.awt.headless=true -Xmx128m -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
#
# Use "-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC" to enable the CMS garbage collector (improved
# response time). If you use that option and you run Tomcat on a machine with
# exactly one CPU chip that contains one or two cores, you should also add
# the "-XX:+CMSIncrementalMode" option.
#JAVA_OPTS="-Djava.awt.headless=true -Xmx128m -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC" # original setting
JAVA_OPTS="-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom -Djava.awt.headless=true -Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -Dapp.profile=vm"

# To enable remote debugging uncomment the following line.
# You will then be able to use a java debugger on port 8000.
JAVA_OPTS="${JAVA_OPTS} -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=8000,server=y,suspend=n"

# Java compiler to use for translating JavaServer Pages (JSPs). You can use all
# compilers that are accepted by Ant's build.compiler property.
#JSP_COMPILER=javac

# Use the Java security manager? (yes/no, default: no)
#TOMCAT8_SECURITY=no

# Number of days to keep logfiles in /var/log/tomcat8. Default is 14 days.
#LOGFILE_DAYS=14
# Whether to compress logfiles older than today's
#LOGFILE_COMPRESS=1

# Location of the JVM temporary directory
# WARNING: This directory will be destroyed and recreated at every startup !
#JVM_TMP=/tmp/tomcat8-temp

# If you run Tomcat on port numbers that are all higher than 1023, then you
# do not need authbind.  It is used for binding Tomcat to lower port numbers.
# (yes/no, default: no)
#AUTHBIND=no

#GEOSERVER_DATA_DIR=/efs/geoserver_data
```

Comment: You have an error in your config files. Run `sudo journalctl -xe`

Comment: @AndreiLupuleasa running `sudo journalctl -xe` isn't very useful. I basically get the same output as `sudo service tomcat8 status`. The reason I don't think it's an error in the config files (although I'm not saying it isn't possible) is because I've done this exact same setup on three separate Mac hosts and not run into this problem, but it did come up on the two Windows hosts I have tried it on.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is most likely a wrong JAVA_HOME path inside the systemd module. Check the JAVA_HOME path inside /etc/systemd/system/tomcat.service, it should not have "jre/" at the end which is wrong for newer Java versions. Try:

```
sudo nano /etc/systemd/system/tomcat.service
```

and remove the trailing "jre/" of the JAVA_HOME path. Then restart tomcat

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl restart tomcat
```

Comment: The tomcat.service file does not exist (there's nothing tomcat related in that directory). I did change the tomcat config file I pasted above to explicitly state the correct path to the jdk and it did not make a difference.